# How to share SharePoint website externally?

Tags: forms-authentication, iis, alternate-access-mapping, public-website, external-users

I'm having issues on next steps to take... I'm currently working on this client exchange portal for our company. Our goal is relativity simple - to have external users sign in and upload documents to us instead of faxing them and vice versa.

I've set up the share point site and created form based authentication for our users.. using this tutorial..

http://sharepoint2013fba.codeplex.com/documentation?

I've tested login as a user and everything is good to go but i need to link it with our external website for them to login to.

Our website is... http://arsprofessionals.com/
When you go on the site you will see the Exchange Portal tab and we would like for our users to click on that tab and go to portal.arsprofessionals.com and have the SharePoint site appear there.

I've read information on Extending and/or applying the Alternative Access Mapping to it.. but I'm a bit confused on which direction to head. I feel like I need to make a change on my external website as well. Can anyone help lead me towards the right direction?

Please let me know if you need me to provide anymore informtion.

Thank you!

Update:

AAM - 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather, your SharePoint server is currently internal only?

You will have to ensure the server either has a public ip, or a port is forwarded from the public ip to the internal server.  Set the dns for portal.arsprofessionals.com to point to that public ip.

If you've done the default setup then right now when accessing your SharePoint site it will ask you if you want to login with either Windows or Forms authentication - so it's a 2 step process to login - choose the login type and then login. If you're ok with that, then simply add an alternate access mapping to the existing site for 'portal.arsprofessionals.com' and everything should be working.

If however you want public users to immediately be directed to the forms login page, then you have to extend the web application. Extending the web application lets you adjust the authentication type for a seperate set of AAM's for your site.  So if users access it via an internal url (e.g. http://myinternalserver.local/) they could immediately be logged in via windows authentication, while users who access it via portal.arsprofessionals.com would be immediately directed to the forms login screen. Once you extend the web application you would setup the AAM's to point to which zone you would like the user redirected to.

Once that is done, then just add a link to your public web site to portal.arsprofessionals.com.

Also, if you're going to be exposing your SharePoint site to the public, you should probably also secure it with an SSL certificate (Add an https binding to the site(s) in IIS, forward port 443 and update the AAM's to specify https://. 
 You should probably also redirect any http requests to https.).

Comment: Thank you for the information Chris. Our website is hosted on our web server so this is a multi tier farm set-up.  

"You will have to ensure the server either has a public ip, or a port is forwarded from the public ip to the internal server. Set the dns for portal.arsprofessionals.com to point to that public ip."

How could i configure this portion? This is the part that i'm stuck at. How do i clarify if the server has a public i.p? @chriscoulson

Comment: Is SharePoint hosted on your web server? If so, the web server will have a public IP and in IIS you can specify that the hostname portal.arsprofessionals.com is bound to the sharepoint website.  So iis will direct any requests to that hostname to SharePoint.

If SharePoint is hosted on your internal network, then you'll have to get a network admin to port forward a public facing ip to it.

Comment: Our Sharepoint is hosted on our sharepoint server and our webserver is hosted on webserver we have. I'll have to work with our networking team to see to find that information. If our external domain is hosted on poweryourname.com will I need to do any work on there? will i need to make any to make any changes on the host record settings? Thank you so much for the help @chris

Comment: The only thing you'd have to do with your domain host would be to ensure that portal.arsprofessionals.com is pointing to the public ip that directs to your SharePoint site.

Comment: Hey Chris, I've forwarded the I.P to our sharepoint. and we are receiving this error. "The site cannot be reached - portal.arsprofessionals.com unexpectedly closed the connection." The link to our portal is [link]https://portal.arsprofessionals.com/ . I've updated the bindings in IIs to forward port 443 and it also reflects that in AAM. Is this a user error or is there a security setting blocking this? @chris

Comment: i'd guess it's a firewall block

Comment: Hey @Chris , you were correct! haha I circled back at the project and i had to do some server farm and firewall work on it first. I was wondering if you could assist me with this.. so we're all connected now but when I access the site from within our companys network our portal.arsprofessionals address changes to.. our server name (arsftpprd/_login).  and when I try to access it outside of our network we are unable to connect to the page at all because it redirects to (arsftpprd/_login).

Comment: Make sure that AAM has the exact url listed that you are trying to connect to. Even http vs https matters.

Comment: Hey @Chris - Hate to bother you but I've tried multiple different settings and still cannot seem to get it to connect correctly. I've included a screenshot of our AAM. and The only zones in our authentication providers is Default and Extranet

Comment: When I visit the portal.arsprofessionals.com, I get an iis error.  You have to check the event viewer to see what the error is.  I don't get redirected to arsftpprd.  We offer a support plan at https://www.visigo.com/products/sharepoint-fba-pack/support-plan/ if you want to have a GoToMeeting debug session.